# SignalR Disconnects Immediately with no code changes on .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-3.1

I am just about ready to pull my hair out. The below code was working flawlessly after my last commit. I made a bunch of significant code changes and refactoring, and somewhere along that process SignalR stopped working properly. After much failed debugging, I reverted my entire codebase back to the last working commit, and SignalR is still not working.

When I load the page, the app starts up and the SignalR connection is started. The negotiation succeeds and the connection to the hub also succeeeds, but is disconnected **immediately**. Here are the only two messages that go through before being disconnected:

[image: SignalR Client Messages.]

There are no console longs, but when I step through the client websockets code I find that the connection is terminated with `code=1000`, and `reason=''`. I am relatively confident that the connection is terminated by the server, but have no way to be sure. My app uses TLS so I can't packet sniff to see what's actually going on.

Here is what I have tried:
Make the server and client timeout much longer.
Make a very short Keepalive interval on client and server.
Tried Edge, Firfox, & connecting from a different computer.
Deleting all of the binaries and restarting Visual Studio.
IISExpress, IIS, and the plain app.
Updated/reinstalled all nuget packages.

Here is the relavent bits from my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  services.AddSignalR(options =>
    {
       options.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
    });
  services.AddControllersWithViews();

  services.AddRazorPages();

  services.ConfigureCoreServices();
  services.ConfigureLiquidMeterServices();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  if (env.IsDevelopment())
  {
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseBrowserLink();
  }
  else
  {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    //The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
  }

  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
  {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp/dist")),
    RequestPath = "/static"
  });

  var webSocketOptions = new WebSocketOptions()
  {
    KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
  };
  app.UseWebSockets(webSocketOptions);

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    { 
      endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
      endpoints.MapHub<LiquidMeterHub>("/lmhub");
      endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

My hub has minimal code, very boilerplate.
Here is my front-end typescript code:

```
class SomeSignalRService{
connection?: signalR.HubConnection;
...
initialize(){
this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl("/lmHub")
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build();

  this.connection.on("clientUpdate", this.clientUpdate.bind(this));
  this.connection.onclose(this.onClose.bind(this));
  
  this.connection.start()
    .then(() => {
      //dispatch connected event;
    });
  
}
```

Comment: You need some logs in order to start an investigation. Set both the client and the server logs to debug level, start again with the test and carefully check the logs written. Without a log or any clue it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Are you debugging on your local machine ? Do you have both the client and the server running locally?

Comment: Disable/check the antivirus and/or firewall, and other stuff that can interfere with networks.

Comment: Not at the computer at the moment, will update with logs on Monday. I am debugging both on the local machine and have tried connecting from another machine, get the same results. Firewall isn't an issue because the the handshake completed and then is disconnected. I have enabled debug logging on both side and I get no errors, warnings or anything indicative of a problem. The logs simply indicate the connection was successful and was immediately closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there was an exception from within the SignalR and Websocket interfaces that would not show up in output unless the following log filters were in place:

```
Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR", LogLevel.Debug);
                    logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Connections", LogLevel.Debug);
                })
```

The error was caused by the serializer not able to parse `double.NaN`. A little odd considering that `NaN` is a valid json value. I added checks to set any double values that were `NaN` to `0`.